# PHP Threading on Gentoo

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, gentoo, threads

PHP on Gentoo supports the `threads` USE flag. As far as I know, PHP does not support true threading; I am only aware of the ability to fork using pcntl_fork(), but this functionality is provided by the `pcntl` USE flag. So what exactly is the point of the `threads` USE flag if PHP does not support threading?

**tl;dr** - What purpose does the `threads` USE flag serve for PHP on Gentoo systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It compiles PHP with thread safety on. PHP doesn't have threads, but this is supposed to allow PHP to run in a threaded environment such as Apache's worker MPM. However, note that PHP thread safety [is highly disputed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681081/is-php-thread-safe).

For more information on the topic, I will shamefully plug [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php/5978844#5978844) to a related question.